# Render images from enother project cause 404(not found) error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unix, carrierwave

Hello I have to separate projects, **images_project** and **site_project**. **site_project** should render images from **images_project** only in development environment from *local machine*. In production it does by SDN.

I share **images_project** path from secrets in 'praser_path'.

I added images path to assets config in **site_project**:

```
# config/initializers/assets.rb

if Rails.env.development? && Rails.application.secrets.parser_path
   # share parser images for admin
   Rails.application.config.assets.paths.push(
     File.join( Rails.application.secrets.parser_path, 'public', 'uploads')
   )
  Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( advert_image/** )
end
```

My model looks for images in local machine

```
# model/image.rb

def file_url(size=nil)
  if Rails.env.development? && Rails.application.secrets.parser_path
    File.join( Rails.application.secrets.parser_path, 'public', file.url(size))
  else
    REMOTE_HOST + file.url(size)
  end
end
```

But when a page with my images renders it processes 404 for all images with this error:

> http://localhost:3000/Users/nick/CODE/work/biz/parser/public/uploads/advert_image/images/374/micro_3117094366.jpg
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

I know that the follow link is bad and images is in 
`file:///Users/nick/CODE/work/biz/parser/public/uploads/advert_image/images/374/micro_3117094366.jpg`
What should I do to get around the server and render images straight from local machine?

Comment: Can you access the image if you paste `http://localhost:3000/Users/nick/CODE/work/biz/parser/public/uploads/advert_image/images/374/micro_3117094366.jpg` in your browser?

Comment: I can't, but if I type this link `/Users/nick/CODE/work/biz/parser/public‌​/uploads/advert_imag‌​e/images/374/micro_3‌​117094366.jpg` I can see the image.

Comment: As you are accessing using application URL, full path of file will not work. Can you check if following URL is accessible. http://localhost:3000/uploads/advert_image/images/374/micro_3117094366.jpg